# What is the problem with this "retraction" $D^2 \to S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, logic, algebraic-topology, continuity, proof-explanation

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, he proves Brouwer's fixed point theorem in dimension $2$.

He shows that if $f: D^2 \to D^2$ has no fixed points, then we can construct a retraction $r: D^2 \to S^1$. However, there cannot exist a retraction from $D^2 \to S^1$. So, $f$ must have a fixed point.

In the proof, the map looks like a perfectly fine map. But actually, it cannot be because there cannot exist such map.

However, I don't see what is wrong with this map. There cannot exist such a retraction, but in the proof, he constructs it. **What is wrong with this $r$?**

> [image]

Comment: Presumably the remainder of the proof explains what is wrong, given that it says "We will show that no such retraction can exist."

Comment: @EricWofsey I know how to prove that part. I already know no retraction can exist. But a retraction is still being constructed. Thus, there must be something inherently wrong with the constructed retraction.

Comment: Yes, that's the point.  It's a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes. But since $r$ cannot exist, there must something wrong in the very definition of $r$. I'm asking what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

He can construct this $r$ precisely because we *assume* we never have $h(x)=x$.The construction is fine and continuous and well-defined **under that assumption**.

From this assumption comes a map we know cannot exist.

So the assumption was wrong.

It's a proof by contradiction. We don't construct a fixpoint, but derive a contradiction from the assumption we don't have any.

Comment: But isn't this saying that if there are no fixed points, then there can exist a retraction? I mean, we just constructed it.

Comment: If there cannot exist a retraction, how are we constructing a well-defined one?

Comment: Of course if there are no fixed points, there is a retraction.  If there are no fixed points, then $0=1$.  Anything follows from a false assumption.

Answer (score 3):

"In the proof, the map looks like a perfectly fine map. But actually, it cannot be because there cannot exist such map."

Which map looks perfectly fine? I'm assuming you mean the map $r$. But he doesn't actually construct a map $r$ -- he gives a *recipe* for constructing $r$, *provided you have the right ingredients*, and one of those is a map with no fixed points.

So: *if* you had such a map, you could build $r$. If I had a billion dollars, I could build a mansion in the middle of Central Park...but I don't, so it's moot.

Now you could try, given *any* map $f$, to build the associated $r$. Let's try that with $f(z) = iz$ (where I'm treating the plane as the complex plane). If $P = 1 + 0i$, then $f(P) = i$, and the arrow from $f(P)$ through $P$ hits the boundary of the circle...at $P$. Great!

What about if $P = 0.5 i$. THen $f(P) = -0.5 + 0i$, and the ray from $f(P)$ through $P$ hits the unit circle...uh...somehwere in the first quadrant.

This is looking pretty good: I pick a $P$, compute $f(P)$, and draw the ray from $f(P)$ through $P$ and see where it hits $S^1$.

OK. Now what if $P = 0 + 0i$. THen $f(P) = P$, and there is no "ray from $f(P)$ through $P$" or more precisely, there are infinitely many to choose from, and no choice makes the map we've been constructing actually *continuous*; to get continuity, we really do need $f(P) \ne P$ for every $P$.

Does that help at all?

Comment: He does actually construct it, but just leaves out the details. The details are: pick an $x \in D^2$, then we have the ray $\gamma_x: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $\gamma_x(t)=(1-t)f(x)+tx$. The image of $\gamma_x$ intersects $S^1$ at a point, say $y_x$: $\mathrm{Im}(\gamma_x) \cap S^1 =\{y_x\}$. Now the map $r: D^2 \to S^1$ is given by $r(x)=y_x$ is the required retraction.

Comment: And that's exactly the construction I describe, a little less formally. And the part that fails, when you don't have a fixed-point-free map, is "the image of $\gamma_x$ intersects $S^1$...", because if $x$ and $f(x)$ are equal, then the "ray" $\gamma_x(t)$ is actually just a constnt function whose image is the single point $x$.